# Why must forward referenced values inside blocks in Scala be lazy?

Tags: scala

> The scope of a name introduced by a declaration or definition is the
>   whole statement sequence containing the binding. However, there is a
>   restriction on forward references in blocks: In a statement sequence
>   `s[1]...s[n]` making up a block, if a simple name in `s[i]` refers to
>   an entity defined by `s[j]` where `j >= i`, then for all `s[k]`
>   between and including `s[i]` and `s[j]`,
>
> - `s[k]` cannot be a variable definition.
> - **If `s[k]` is a value definition, it must be `lazy`.**

**Edit:** I am not sure Mikaël Mayer's answer actually explained everything. Consider:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(x)
    lazy val x: Int = 6
  }
}
```

Here, the lazy value `x` definitely has to be read/evaluated before it is actually defined in the code! Which would contradict Mikaël's claim that lazy evaluation does away with the need to evaluate things before they are defined.

Comment: Your question is missing the crucial "in blocks" part. Forward references in general have no such restriction, and in my experience you're rarely if ever going to want to do this kind of thing in a block.

Comment: In blocks as opposed to in object or class definitions you mean?

Comment: Right. I'm actually a little surprised forward references in blocks are allowed at all.

Comment: Why? Scala frequently uses many nested functions, this rule just makes it a little more flexible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you cannot have this:

```
val e: Int = 2
val a: Int = b+c
val b: Int = c
val c: Int = 1
val d: Int = 0
```

because value c is not yet defined at the time of the definition of a. Because a references c, all values between a and c should be lazy so that the dependency is avoided

```
val e: Int = 2
lazy val a: Int = b+c
lazy val b: Int = c
lazy val c: Int = 1
val d: Int = 0
```

This in fact translates a, b and c as objects whose value is initialized when it is read, which would be after the declaration, i.e. this would be equivalent to:

```
val e: Int = 2
var a: LazyEval[Int] = null
var b: LazyEval[Int] = null
var c: LazyEval[Int] = null
a = new LazyEval[Int] {
  def evalInternal() = b.eval() + c.eval()
}
b = new LazyEval[Int] {
  def evalInternal() = c.eval()
}
c = new LazyEval[Int] {
  def evalInternal() = 1
}
val d = 0
```

where `LazyEval` would be something like the following (implemented by the compiler itself)

```
class LazyEval[T] {
  var value: T = _
  var computed: Boolean = false
  def evalInternal(): T // Abstract method to be overriden
  def eval(): T = {
     if(computed) value else {
       value = evalInternal()
       computed = true
       value
     }
  }
}
```

**Edit**

vals don't really exist in java. They are local variables or do not exist in computation. Therefore, the declaration of lazy val exists before anything is done. And remember that closures are implemented in Scala.
Your block would be rewritten as it:

```
  object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      // Declare all variables, val, vars.
      var x: Lazy[Int] = null
      // No more variables to declare. Lazy/or not variable definitions
      x = new LazyEval[Int] {
        def evalInternal() = 6
      }
      // Now the code starts
      println(x)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey, please see my edit, I don't think your answer is correct.

Comment: So Scala essentially has [hoisting like JavaScript](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092), but with restrictions? Please provide a source on this, it seems like a major Scala detail I missed. Also, damn it, I started a bounty before noticing your edit...

Comment: What you say about how local lazies are translated is not how it looks on 2.11.  A `runtime.IntRef` is allocated and an accessor invoked which computes `x` lazily. There is no actual or conceptual reordering which puts decls first and "real" code last, says `-Xprint:typer`. From `:javap -prv`, it passes around the Ref objects to `a$1`, `a$lzycompute$1` etc which perform the evaluations.

Comment: Indeed, but it provides an explanation about the reordering.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to avoid references to entities which are provably uninitialized (or which are maybe uninitialized).

In a block, assignments occur in source order, but in a class template, members can be overridden and initialized early.

For instance,

```
{ val a = b ; val b = 1 }  // if allowed, value of a is undefined
```

but in a template

```
class X { val a = b ; val b = 1 }       // warning only
val x = new { override val b = 2 } with X
x.a  // this is 2
class Y(override val b: Int) extends X  // similarly
```

You also want to avoid this:

```
locally {
  def a = c
  val b = 2     // everything in-between must be lazy, too
  def c = b + 1 
}
```

Local objects are explicitly the same as lazy vals:

```
{ object p { val x = o.y } ; object o { val y = 1 } }
```

Other kinds of forward reference:

```
{ val x: X = 3 ; type X = Int }
```

The spec talks about forward references to "entities" -- a "name refers to an entity" -- which elsewhere means both terms and types, but obviously it really means only terms here.

It will let you harm yourself:

```
{ def a: Int = b ; def b: Int = a; a }
```

Maybe your mode of self-destruction must be well-defined. Then it's OK.